# Download firebase storage file to computer

Tags: reactjs, firebase-storage

> Note: I want to download the file on the local storage.

Get firebase file

```
Firebase.storage().ref('file.jpg').getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
   var a = document.createElement("a")
   document.body.appendChild(a)
   a.style = "display: none"
   a.href = url
   a.download = 'file'
   a.click()
}).catch(function(msg) {
    // catch error here
})
```

Tried this method to download with invisible anchor tag. On click the page is redirected to the firebase storage but the downloader is not invoked.

> CORS is configured properly

Is there any chance to invoke the browser to download files from firebase storage on button click.

I tried the above code on React JS project but it seems to be broken.

Comment: It's given in the docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url

Comment: I tried that method, It only generated a blob with 2 json data.

Comment: Can you try this module instead? https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-download

Comment: Here is the repo: https://github.com/kennethjiang/js-file-download. The last commit is 24 days ago so it looks like some work is still being done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I download image on firebase storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619510/how-can-i-download-image-on-firebase-storage)

Answer (score 2):

Check if the path is complete and try this code:

```
storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    if (link.download !== undefined) {
        link.setAttribute("href", url);
        link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
})
```

The code on docs doesn't work on my project.

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function(event) {
    var blob = xhr.response;
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url